# How do I clear a Model's :has_many associations without writing to the database in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, orm

For the sake of this question, let's say I have a very simple model:

```
class DystopianFuture::Human < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :hobbies
 validates :hobbies, :presence => {message: 'Please pick at least 1 Hobby!!'}
end
```

The problem is that when a human is updating their hobbies on a form and they don't pick any hobbies, there's no way for me to reflect this in the code without actually deleting all the associations.

So, say the action looks like this:

```
def update
 hobbies = params[:hobbies]
 human = Human.find(params[:id])

 #ideally here I'd like to go
 human.hobbies.clear
 #but this updates the db immediately

 if hobbies && hobbies.any?
  human.hobbies.build(hobbies)
 end

 if human.save
  #great
 else
  #crap
 end
end
```

Notice the human.hobbies.clear line. I'd like to call this to make sure I'm only saving the new hobbies. It means I can also check to see if the user hasn't checked any hobbies on the form.

But I can't do that as it clears the db. I don't want to write anything to the database unless I know the model is valid.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Initialy I also did this same way. Then found out one solution for this issue.

You need to do something like this

```
params[:heman][:hobby_ids]=[] if params[:human][:hobby_ids].nil?
```

Then check

```
if human.update_attributes(params[:human])
```

Hope you will get some idea...

**EDIT:**

Make hobbies params like this

```
hobbies = { hobbies_attributes: [
    { title: 'h1' },
    { title: 'h2' },
    { title: 'h3', _destroy: '1' } # existing hobby 
  ]}

if Human.update_atttributes(hobbies)  # use this condition
```

For this you need to declare `accepts_nested_attributes_for :hobbies, allow_destroy: true` in your Human model.

See more about this here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

You can try https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form for this purpose..

Comment: hmm not sure this is relevant to this question? Or maybe I've misunderstood thaha. Hobbies is an association, there is no "hobby_ids" attribute, so update_attributes won't work, no?

Comment: I think in your case hobby_ids will be params[:hobbies](contain the ids of selected hibbies). The problem here is instead of updating you are deleting then creating. That needs to be changed.

Comment: You can do this way also..  Not recommended...   if hobbies && hobbies.any?
  human.hobbies.clear
  human.hobbies.create(hobbies)
  #great
 else
  #crap
 end

Comment: no because human.hobbies.clear  will write to the db. I don't want that